# How to make 2 country/state "graphics" to work the same way using Action Filter

Tags: tableau-api, action-filter, country

I'm having trouble making my 2 crountry "graphics" to work the same way.
Let me explain.

First I have my SS here of how it is in the begining.:
[before I click in some UF to filter both of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwx4Y.png)

Then I have an SS After clicking in some UF:

[After clicking some UF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjeBY.png)

If you notice, the bellow figure (green one) have all UF's in both SS's, when I click in one to filter it, some UFs become shadows and the one I clicked become Highlighted...

But the above figure(red one) Before the filtering are all the same green and red.
after I click in some UF in green all the other ufs in red disapear, the scale became one single color.

I need to make the red one to work the same way as green one, shadowing the other UFs, highligthing the UF I clicked in the green one.. (Or vice-versa, since I can filter by red or green) and the scale to don't change.

Is it possible to do what I want?
How can I do it?

A friend of mine says it might be because the filter is being aplied before the complete sample enter the "graphic" making it only see the filtered UF(STATE)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check your filters. In your red example, once you select a state, notice how the color legend only reads one value. So the act of clicking it, is triggering a filter for only that state. Whereas your green example, it only shadows out the others, so no filter is engaged.

Comment: I clicked on the green one to put the filter.in the green one I can click on other UFs, o ir filters the other one, if I do that, the red one will only show the UF I click on the green.
If I click on the red one, the red one will became shadow, and the green one will only show the UF I clicked on the red one.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your workbook? or with sample data with the same behavior?

Comment: Sorry, can't confidential data... I guess it could be used for every kind of data to use in colors. Put the 2 graphics together and click in some state. in one of then...